# Filter an array in Angular from View

Tags: angularjs

I'm working with a grid and I would like to fill it with data from arrays.

I have an array of columns, rows and data

```
$scope.columns = [
  { id: "1", name: "Col 1" },
  { id: "2", name: "Col 2" },
  { id: "3", name: "Col 3" },
  { id: "4", name: "Col 4" }
];

$scope.rows = [
  { id: "1", name: "Row 1" },
  { id: "2", name: "Row 2" },
  { id: "3", name: "Row 3" },
  { id: "4", name: "row 4" }
];

$scope.data = [
  { idRow: "1", idCol: "1", value: "Jhon" },
  { idRow: "1", idCol: "2", value: "Peter" },
  { idRow: "2", idCol: "1", value: "Mary" },
  { idRow: "3", idCol: "2", value: "Paul" }
];
```

I would like to fill the grid, and I am doing it (not well) with this code in the View.

This is because I can't filter the `data` array using `idRow` and `idCol` from View.

This code works, but it is no good at all.
What are the improvements that You would share with me ?

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th ng-repeat="he in columns">{{he.name}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="pointer" ng-repeat="fi in rows">
      <td>{{fi.name}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="co in columns">
        <label ng-repeat="es in data" ng-if="es.idRow == fi.id && es.idCol == co.id">
          {{es.vale}}   
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

BTW: What is the way to elimitate duplicates in an array (some like distinct) and to sort it from view?

As You can see, I'm new with Angularjs.

Thanks, Capitán S.

Comment: What is `cols` in `<td ng-repeat="co in cols">` - I'm assuming it's different to `columns` (which you have listed already).

Comment: sorry. Must be columns. I´ve changed the names from spanish to english and I made that mistake in the process

Comment: What I want to do is ask for a specific value in the "data" array. Not do a loop for every cell to the array.

Comment: you really should consider consolidating the data into the objects you are trying to represent, rather than a representation of your output.  i.e. don't try to create arrays for rows and columns, unless it is directly relevant to the data itself.

Comment: for example, why are you trying to display a name only in the first column in the second row, and only one name in the second column of the third row? is there some reason that (2,2) and (3,1) need to be empty?

Comment: In the real app, "rows" are studies and "columns" are dates. Not all the studies have results in all the dates

Comment: and how many columns are you talking about here? do you have a finite amount of columns or are the number of columns dynamic?

Comment: It is dynamic. For example 100 Studies and 10 dates. So I will have arround  700 results. 
I want to avoid read these 700 values, every time I enter a cell. With the ng-repeat sentence, I'm doing that for every "<label>"

Answer (score 0):

Its 'fi.id' not 'fi.ID or co.ID'

```
     <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th ng-repeat="he in columns track by $index">{{he.name}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="pointer" ng-repeat="fi in rows track by $index">
          <td>{{fi.name}}</td>
          <td ng-repeat="co in columns track by $index" >
            <label ng-repeat="d in data track by $index" ng-if="d.idRow == fi.id && d.idCol == co.id">
              {{d.value}}
            </label>
          </td>           
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

About duplicates, maybe filter your array in controller. You can use [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
 var arr = [1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 5]
 var newA = arr.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
    return index == self.indexOf(elem);
  })
```

newA is [1, 4, 5]

Comment: You are right. Next time I will check the example before post it.